# Converting a collection of Awaitables to a time-ordered AsyncGenerator in Hack

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, generator, hacklang

I am trying to implement Rx stream/observable merging with Hack async, and a core step is described by the title. A code version of this step would look something like this:

```php
<?hh // strict
async function foo(Awaitable<Iterable<T>> $collection): Awaitable<void> {
  $ordered_generator = async_collection_to_gen($collection) // (**)
  foreach($ordered_generator await as $v) {
    // do something with each awaited value in the time-order they are resolved
  }
}
```

However, after mulling it over, I don't think I *can* write the starred `(**)` function. I've found that at some point or another, the implementations I've tried require functionality akin to JS's `Promise.race`, which resolves when the first of a collection Promises resolves/rejects. However, all of [Hack's Awaitable collection helpers](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/async/utility-functions) create an Awaitable of a *fully* resolved collection. Furthermore, Hack doesn't permit that we don't `await` async calls from `async function`s, which I've also found to be necessary.

Is it possible to anyone's knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible actually! I dug around and stumbled upon [a fork of asio-utilities](https://github.com/jano/asio-utilities/tree/master/src) by @jano implementing an `AsyncPoll` class. [See PR for usage.](https://github.com/hhvm/asio-utilities/pull/11) It does exactly as I hoped.

So it turns out, there is an `Awaitable` called `ConditionWaitHandle` with `succeed` and `fail` methods*  that can be invoked by any context ([so long as the underlying WaitHandle hasn't expired yet](https://github.com/jano/asio-utilities/blob/master/src/AsyncCondition.php#L49)), forcing the `ConditionWaitHandle` to resolve with the passed values.

I gave the code a hard look, and underneath it all, it works by successive `Awaitable` races, which `ConditionWaitHandle` permits. More specifically, the collection of `Awaitable`s is compressed via `AwaitAllWaitHandles` (aka `\HH\Asio\v`) which resolves as slowly as the slowest `Awaitable`, then nested within a `ConditionWaitHandle`. Each `Awaitable` is awaited in an `async function` that triggers the common `ConditionWaitHandle`, concluding the race. This is repeated until the `Awaitable`s have all resolved.

Here's a more compact implementation of a race using the same philosophy:

```php
<?hh
function wait(int $i): Awaitable<void> {
    return Race::wrap(async { await HH\Asio\usleep($i); return $i; });
}
// $wait_handle = null;
class Race {
    public static ?ConditionWaitHandle $handle = null;
    public static async function wrap<T>(Awaitable<T> $v): Awaitable<void> {
        $ret = await $v;
        $handle = self::$handle;
        invariant(!is_null($handle), '');
        $handle->succeed($ret);
    }
}
Race::$handle = ConditionWaitHandle::create(
    \HH\Asio\v(
        Vector{
            (wait(1))->getWaitHandle(), 
            (wait(1000000))->getWaitHandle()
        }
    )
);
printf("%d microsecond `wait` wins!", \HH\Asio\join(Race::$handle));
```

Very elegant solution, thanks @jano!

*<sup>(the semblance to promises/deferred intensifies)</sup>

---

I am curious how premature completion via `ConditionWaitHandle` meshes with the philosophy that [all `Awaitable`s should run to completion](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5428#issuecomment-107750308).